# How to read NEXTJS route from router.query if it was matched in to static page?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-router

I would like to have static routes in my application while saving ability to read them somewhere.

For example:

```
-/Pages
--index.js
--/Account
---Settings.js
---[AccountPages].js
```

Somewhere in my codebase:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const {AccountPages} = router.query
```

Problem is that `AccountPages`  will return some value for any page but `account/settings`

Is it possible to read `AccountPages` for route that was matched in to static page?

Comment: What do you mean by "route that was matched in to static page"? You should be able to access `router.query` on any page you want.

Comment: if my route is /account/settings then calling 

router.query somewhere in the code will return empty object, while calling it from 
/account/dynamic_route

router.query will return {"accountsPages"}

Comment: You get an empty object in `/account/settings` because there are no query params on that path. If you just want to access the path you can use `router.asPath` instead.